# TestCafe - Test fails onGetBposShellInfoNavBarData

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am running TestCafe version 0.22.0 on Win10. I am not sure if my issue has something with the Win10 or not but unfortunately, I don´t have another computer to test on. The issue is that my tests fail with error message "GetBposShellInfoNavBarData failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Here is the simple code I use:

Error on page "https://outlook.live.com/mail/inbox":      GetBposShellInfoNavBarData failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Browser: Chrome 69.0.3497 / Windows 10.0.0

```
await t.click('body > section > div > div > nav > div > div > div > a');
await t.typeText('#i0116', login);
await t.click('#idSIButton9');
await t.typeText('#i0118', password);
await t.click('#idSIButton9');
await t.maximizeWindow();
```

Test fails on this **t.maximizeWindow().** It also fails with same error on next "t.click(Selector...) if I comment out t.maximizeWindow() line.

Comment: Without testing myself, it sounds like an error on the page itself rather than originating from testcafe. If you manually do the same actions do you see the same error in the console? You can ignore js errors with `--skip-js-errors`

Answer (score 1):

As @ioseph properly mentioned, this error occurs on your web page and is not related to TestCafe.

I recommend that you address this error on your website and run your tests again.

Alternatively, you can use the [--skip-js-error](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors)s argument to ignore such errors.